# How to add multidimensional array to an element of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add a multidimensional array somewhere inside another multidimensional array. I have this code example to explain what I try to do and what goes wrong:

```
    $a_base =   [
                'wop' => 
                    [
                        'tik' => 
                            [
                                'a' => 190,
                                'b' => 323,
                                'c' => 342
                            ],
                        'tak' =>
                            [
                                'a' => 142,
                                'b' => 654,
                                'c' => 785
                            ]
                    ],
                'wap' =>
                    [
                        'top' => 
                            [
                                'a' => 564,
                                'b' => 667,
                                'c' => 968
                            ],
                        'top' =>
                            [
                                'a' => 603,
                                'b' => 694,
                                'c' => 102
                            ]
                    ]
            ];

$a_addon =  [
                'tok' =>
                    [
                        'a' => 883,
                        'b' => 993,
                        'c' => 878

                    ]
            ];


array_push($a_base['wop'], $a_addon);
var_dump($a_base);
```

The result is this:

```
array(2) {
  ["wop"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tik"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["a"]=>
      int(190)
      ["b"]=>
      int(323)
      ["c"]=>
      int(342)
    }
    ["tak"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["a"]=>
      int(142)
      ["b"]=>
      int(654)
      ["c"]=>
      int(785)
    }
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["tok"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["a"]=>
        int(883)
        ["b"]=>
        int(993)
        ["c"]=>
        int(878)
      }
    }
  }
  ["wap"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["top"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["a"]=>
      int(603)
      ["b"]=>
      int(694)
      ["c"]=>
      int(102)
    }
  }
}
```

But what I need is this (without the [0]=> array(1) {...}):

```
array(2) {
  ["wop"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tik"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["a"]=>
      int(190)
      ["b"]=>
      int(323)
      ["c"]=>
      int(342)
    }
    ["tak"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["a"]=>
      int(142)
      ["b"]=>
      int(654)
      ["c"]=>
      int(785)
    }
    ["tok"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["a"]=>
      int(883)
      ["b"]=>
      int(993)
      ["c"]=>
      int(878)
    }
  }
  ["wap"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["top"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["a"]=>
      int(603)
      ["b"]=>
      int(694)
      ["c"]=>
      int(102)
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried other functions like array_combine et cetera, but without success. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

An array union will work perfectly as a functionless array merging technique on your associative arrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Qa5hY))

```
$a_base['wop'] += $a_addon;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge()`

```
$a_base['wop'] = array_merge($a_base['wop'], $a_addon);
```

Comment: Why didn't you close this duplicate, Barmar?